# How do i check the state of file field

Tags: php, file

when i used this statement to check if file field is empty or not, it had'nt succed,

i have tried :

1. `if( $_files['f1'] ['size'] ===0 ){}`      X
2. `if (empty($_FILES['f1']['error'] === 0)){}`    X
3. `if( $_files['f1'] ['name'] ===0 ){}`      X

**note**: There are no syntax error.

2- file field name is :f1

What is the solution?

Comment: You could check against the upload constants for an error `if($_FILES['f1']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {...}`

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as does your posted code. As soon as someone accesses your uploading form, they have 2 options made available to them. 1) The browse button 2) The Submit button. If you wish to check whether they chose a file or not, then you need to use an `if(isset` condition for the file field, and not check whether the file is `0` in size.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 if ($_FILES['f1']['name'] === '') {
 }
```

or

```
if ($_FILES["f1"]["error"] > 0) {
}
```